# Per server welcome message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i am trying to make my bot register a guild on a json file when it joins a server so i could try on making a multiple server welc cmds but it wont work can you help me please

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
fright = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!",  activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="discord.gg/antis"), status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb,  intents=intents)


@fright.event
async def on_ready():
    print('on')

@fright.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('welcome.json', 'r') as f:
        cha = json.load(f)

    cha[str(guild.channel.id)] = "test"

    with open('welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(cha, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Why did you tag discord.js if you're using discord.py

Comment: If my answer was correct make sure to check mark it so people know it was answered

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your line of code (2) you have command_prefix = !! you need that to be like this

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import json

def get_prefix(client, message):
  with open ('welcome.json', 'r') as f:
    cha= json.load(f)
  return cha[str(message.guild.id)]




intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)  #need to go and enable intents in discord developer settings for the bot or else it wont see the user lists 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)
```

This makes it more clear for what intents you are calling out, also making it so commands are case sensitive now for the command should look like this

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('welcome.json', 'r') as f:
        cha = json.load(f)

    cha[str(guild.channel.id)] = "test"

    with open('welcome.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(cha, f, indent=4)

    print(f"{guild.name} has invited (BOT_NAME)")
```

Comment: This is not what the OP has asked for. You have told them how to make a per guild prefix instead of a per guild welcome message

Comment: he asked how to add the guild id into a json with the prefix add to it